# Click event fires twice for item inside a loop

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So the thing is that I have **leafletjs** map, using some data that I get from fetch I add new markers to the map. There is a loop going through the data and it creates and puts a new marker for both "destination from" and "destination to".

The problem is that after the click on one of the markers the event fires twice. I have tried for example using a variable holding last click time and comparing it with a new one, but it does not fix the problem. When I change the loop so it adds only 1 marker the event still fires twice. Can you see what might be the cause?

The other additional problem (if someone can see why is that happening) is that after clicking one of the **markers (from/to)** (event fires twice) and click **any other one (that doesn't belong to the previously clicked pair)** I get undefined error on **package.addressFrom**

```
function prepare(data)
{
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; ++i)
    {
        var markeFrom = L.marker([data[i].latFrom, data[i].lngFrom], {myCustomClass: data[i].id}).addTo(myMapAll).on('click', markerClicked);
        var markerTo = L.marker([data[i].latTo, data[i].lngTo], {myCustomClass: data[i].id}).addTo(myMapAll).on('click', markerClicked);
        
        packageInfo["id"] = data[i].id;
        packageInfo["addressFrom"] = data[i].destinationFrom;
        packageInfo["addressTo"] = data[i].destinationTo;
        packageInfo["recipient"] = data[i].recipient;
        packageMapInfoArr.push(packageInfo);
    }
}

function markerClicked() 
{
    var clickedMarkerId = this.options.myCustomClass;
    var package = packageMapInfoArr.find(x => x.id === clickedMarkerId);
    
    alert('From:' + package.addressFrom + '\n' +
            'To:' + package.addressTo + '\n' +
            'Recipient:' + package.recipient);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the .addTo method returns the *layer* instead of the *marker*, you are adding your event handlers to the wrong thing.

Comment: Did you try beside to add ```.on('click', markerClicked);``` at the end to do after creating the marker :  ```markerFrom.on('click', markerClicked);```  ? also you can check that you don't create the same marker twice by accident.. (its low chance but worth to check).. also you can add (e) to markerClicked function and console log (e) to see what you are getting..

Comment: @Elnatanvazana Adding after creating doesn't help. Also have tried adding 'e' to the function call before, but I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: e" error. I am more used to using jQuery for click events, so I don't really know why it happens

Comment: @JamesSmith did you do ```function markerClicked(e){ console.log(e) }``` ? if yes please share what you are getting, also you can try to do ```var markerTo = L.marker([data[i].latTo, data[i].lngTo], {myCustomClass: data[i].id}).on('click', markerClicked);```, ```markerTo.addTo(myMapAll)```

Comment: @Elnatanvazana I've added logs at the end of the problem description

Comment: @Elnatanvazana After that event still fires twice

Comment: @JamesSmith i created code pen with two markers and its working. https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/jOrdPyX  i will try to re create your problem and fix it. feel free to play around with the codepen, it might be that your problem is coming from different place in your code..

Comment: As for your additional problem, you should not reuse the same packageInfo object. If you need help on that, you should make it a separate question.

Comment: @Elnatanvazana Well, probably the problem was with Safari that I was using as Ivan has stated. However thank you for trying to help!

Comment: @ghybs Thanks, I have made a few changes to add separate object for 2 markers in the loop and it is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those screenshots seem to be from the Safari web browser, so chances are that you're hitting [known Leaflet issue #7255](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255). Using any other web browser should clarify if this is the case.

There is no clean solution to this bug at the time of this writing, but the current workaround is to disable the `tap` handler (by means of [the `tap` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-tap) when initializing the `L.Map` instance)

Comment: All right... I checked and it worked fine on chrome, later on I set the tap option to false and it is fine on Safari now too.